# The opcode "load the next word into Register A" mentioned by Gandalf61

Tags: cpu

Gandalf61 mentions [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/113478/152243) that there are opcodes that "load the next word into Register A", treat the bits at the next address defined by program counter as data and loads this data. I am interested in examples of computers and CPUs that have such as opcode.

*Context: Learning basic computer architecture, and interested in how to load constants into registers. In nandgame.com and "nand to Tetris" course (that uses "hack computer" and "hack assembly"), there is "a-instruction", specified by 15th bit set to 0, that treats the instruction as 15 bits of data. With "load immediate" instruction (or similar name) in a few real-world CPUs I read about, a few bits will be treated as data and loaded into register. I am interested overall in how a constant defined in assembly or in a program gets into the CPU. Have not seen any that worked like Gandalf61 mentioned, therefore asking.*

Comment: (I seem to remember few architectures that *don't* feature a word size *load immediate*, whether as a separate *op code* or via one *addressing mode* of a *load* instruction. MIPS for one had to assemble word size literals, use of `LUI` (Load Upper Immediate) was suggested.)

Comment: Thanks yes I came across the LUI approach too. I mostly want to know how much of what I learnt from nandgame is "real" and how much is simplified fiction, and what Gandalf61 mentioned seems reasonable, but have not seen in anywhere (maybe he was "simplifying" and that type of instruction, "load next word into register", has not been used. )

Answer (score 2):

Many/most architectures include this kind of instruction.  It might be known as "load immediate" or "move" with an immediate/literal/constant value.  See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode#Immediate/literal, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture#Data_handling_and_memory_operations, or look into the instruction sets of any of your favorite computer architectures.

Comment: Thanks, I was specifically wondering about where an opcode specifies that the next word (not part of the current word) should be loaded into some register. The "load immediate" seems to specify that part of the current instruction should be loaded/interpreted as data, not the following instruction.

Comment: @user52174, you might have to review some instruction architectures to see what you can find, then.  In some architectures, such as x86, there is no notion of "current word" or "next word".

Comment: ok that sounds weird. do you have any reference to it or link to any good place to read about it?

Comment: @user52174 you can look up the x86 mov instruction - it has lots of versions - the ones that load 32 bits are 32 bits longer than the ones that don't. You could think of it as a "next byte" and the CPU reads 4 extra bytes after the instruction. x86 instructions have variable length (even the instruction part) and we think of the value as part of the instruction. The "next word" thing is more applicable to architectures where every instruction is the same size.

Comment: @user253751 Thanks. Have looked at the mov instruction during my study of how data in program would be loaded into register. To use mov on x86 for that, is it something like mov some_register, constant_value, for example mov EAX, 4294967295 or mov EDX, 4294967295? I assume you do not mean something like "mov EAX, [EIP]" (I assume EIP is program counter), it would be closer to how I interpreted Gandalf61's comment (and I also assume such an instruction would not increment program counter and therefore not work very well. )

Comment: @user52174 yes that's how it works *in x86*.

Comment: @user253751 OK thanks. Was I also right that "mov some_registry, program_counter" ("mov EAX, [EIP]" maybe it is) would not work for this, because the program counter would not be incremented? It was how I interpreted Gandalf61's comment, but I see how he could have meant the mov register, constant or load immediate.

Comment: @user253751 Thanks. This made sense and cleared out my question. Thanks also to D.W for starting this thread that cleared things out. One last thing, "mov EAX, 0x11223344" is just loading the number 287454020, and you mean it increments the EIP an extra step because the mov instruction always does that if it loads constant bigger than can fit in one instruction?

Comment: @user253751 OK so both work. Good to know, thank you very much for clearing it up for me.

Comment: @user253751 I have no trouble at all understanding "mov register, constant". But, it seems weird that "mov eax, [ebx]" would increment the instruction counter twice (skip over the next one), and it is implied it has to if "mov eax, [EIP++]" and constant as the next instruction would work the same as "mov eax, constant".

Comment: @user253751 it seems to me like incrementing program counter with an instruction, and getting data at the program counter, cannot be done in exact same compiled code as "mov register, constant". "mov eax, [EIP = address]" sets EIP, it does not just read from it. would doubt it is allowed. maybe it is, I am a super beginner, but it does not seem like it to me.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the comments about x86:

One of x86's "load immediate" instructions is `MOV eax, 0x11223344` [encoded as](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_176.html) `B8 44 33 22 11` (x86 is little-endian).

There are two ways you could view this instruction.

Officially, it's a 5-byte-long instruction `MOV eax, 0x11223344` which stores the value 0x11223344 into eax.

But you could also view this as a 1-byte instruction `MOV eax, next 4 bytes from EIP` (encoded as `B8`) followed by the 4-byte value 0x11223344.

These are two different ways to think about the exact same machine code bytes which make the processor do the exact same thing.

Comment: Thanks. But, I still do not think "MOV eax, next 4 bytes from EDX" seems like it would increment the program counter an extra step (and skip over the next instruction that might be 0x11223344. ) So I still do not see that "MOV eax, next 4 bytes from EIP" would (and then jump directly to the instruction after "0x11223344". ) And if it does not, then it can't be exact same machine code bytes. I might be missing something, this is my thoughts at the moment.

Comment: I've tested it as far as I could in x86 emulators now, and it does not seem possible to do MOV eax, [EIP] with the number after that as its own "instruction" and get exact same machine code as MOV eax, number. It only increments the program counter by one, so it would not make sense. And getting the value for the instruction pointer seems a bit tricky as well, to start with.

Comment: @user52174 There is no "MOV eax, next 4 bytes from EDX" instruction. If there was, it would increment EDX by 4 bytes, not EIP. Some architectures do have this type of instruction.

Comment: You are the one who mentioned "hypothetical" incrementing EIP, "there is literally no difference between "mov EAX, 0x11223344" and (hypothetically) "mov EAX, [EIP++]" followed by 0x11223344. They make the exact same bytes of machine code and do exactly the same thing". Now you deleted that, but as I said, it does not at all seem to be "exact same machine code", that seems to be a false statement. Thank you for your comments overall, has been helpful.

Comment: @user52174 I'm trying to make the point that the byte `B8` is totally indistinguishable from an instruction called `mov EAX, [EIP++]` or `mov EAX, next 4 bytes from EIP`. Since that instruction isn't actually in the manuals, we have to make up a name for it. If you really wanted, you *could* make an assembler where the instruction `mov EAX, [EIP++]` translates to `B8`

Comment: And that seems false to me. You skip over details. Specifically, the bytes B8 44 33 22 11 also tell the program counter to hop two times (I assume, is this true? ) mov EAX, [address] does not increment program counter in the way that it could fetch the word following that instruction. you are not making any point when you make false analogies. I already know computers executive machine instructions, so not sure what the point is supposed to be. "you could literally do this, hypothetically, except you could not", not a very good point.

Comment: @user52174 The byte B8 tells the CPU to increment the program counter by 1, copy 4 bytes from the program counter address to EAX, then increment the program counter by 4.

Comment: That seems false to me. "mov EAX, [ECX]" if I understand copies the data in RAM at the address in ECX register, and moves it to EAX register. if it also increments program counter multiple times like 4 times, how could a program read in the next instruction if it skips it? I have no problem understanding the normal mov instruction example, I just do not see or agree with the "weird" case of it that we are talking about.

Comment: @user52174 no, "mov EAX, [ECX]" (`8B 01`) does not increment the program counter 4 times. It increments the program counter twice. Different instructions are different.

Comment: Yes mov EAX, [ECX] is 8B01. mov EAX, [ECX++] is not allowed, and you cheery pick the actual machine code for instructions that are real, to make a case for non real ones. You may be right that mov EAX, [EIP] would somehow skip over multiple follow instructions and be able to get data crammed into that address, but it does not add up to me. The other part, how a mov instruction can do things over many words, does.

Comment: I have a hard time seeing 8B01 would increment PC twice, since it is just 16 bit, and each word is 16 bit in x86 architecture if I understand. If it did increment by 2, what about the next instruction that is skipped?

Comment: from your comment on my follow up question (to clear out what the misunderstanding was), I see now what it is. we are talking about different things. you use MOV eax, next 4 bytes from EIP as an analogy for what B8 44 33 22 11 does. I was talking about a more literal example, and I still do not think my literal one would work. thank you for your comments and answer that helped me understand a lot more.

Comment: @user52174 Every byte has a separate address.

Comment: thanks found that in the book The X86 Microprocessors: Architecture And Programming (8086 To Pentium) as well. good to know for my studies of basics of how CPU works. thanks very much for help.